# How to improve jquery datatable performance to load large data efficiently with 1,00,000 records

Tags: java, jquery, pagination, spring-data-jpa

I am using jquery datatable with minimal configuration to showcase data on my website. I have 1,00,000 records to show in datatable.

Currently the datatable is taking too much time to initialize the records. so systems going to hangout mode.

I am using JSON return data from java side.

jquery code here:

```
$("button#searchbutton").click(function() {                          
                          var fromDate = $("#fD").val();
                          var toDate = $("#tD").val();
                          url = "/Search?fromDate="+fromDate+"&toDate="+toDate;                         
                         $('#table').DataTable({
                              "ajax" : url,
                              "bDestroy":true,
                                "columns":[
                                    {"data": "txnid" },
                                    {"data": "date"},
                                    {"data": "Amount"}                                        
                                   ],
                                   "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
                                   "language": {
                                       "lengthMenu": "| View _MENU_ records per page",
                                       "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",
                                       "infoEmpty": "No records available",
                                       "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
                                   },
                                   "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                                  "lengthChange": false
                          });
                    });
```

Server Side Code here:

```
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
@RequestMapping(value = "/Search", produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody JSONObject getPendingList(@RequestParam(required = false) String fromDate,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String toDate,Model model) throws ParseException 
    {           
    List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    Date fromDate1 = null;
    Date toDate1 = null;
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(fromDate)) {
        fromDate1 = null;
    } else {
        fromDate1 = sf.parse(fromDate);
    }
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(toDate)) {
        toDate1 = null;
    } else {
        toDate1 = sf.parse(toDate);
    }
        List<AccountDetails> list2 = service.getList(fromDate1, toDate1);   
        JSONObject ajson = null;
        if (list2 != null && list2.size() != 0) {
            for (AccountDetails deatils : list2) {
                Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
                map.put("txnid", deatils.getTxnid());
                map.put("amount", deatils.getAmount());
                if(deatils.getTxnDate() != null){
                map.put("date", sf.format(deatils.getTxnDate()));
                }else{
                    map.put("date", "");
                }
                list.add(map);
            }
            ajson = new JSONObject();
            ajson.put("data", list);
        }else {
            ajson = new JSONObject();
            ajson.put("data", null);
        }
    }
```

Service Interface Here:

```
public List<AccountDetails> getList(fromDate1, toDate1);
```

Implementation Here:

```
@Override
    public List<AccountDetails> getList(Date fromDate, Date toDate) {
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(AccountDetails.class);
    System.out.println(fromDate+"********"+toDate);
        if (fromDate != null) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("txnDate", fromDate));
        }
        if (toDate != null) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.le("txnDate", toDate));
        }
        return criteria.list();
    }
```

What are your suggestions for improving the load time?

Comment: Doesn't matter what you do.  1mill records will always take a long time to show as it's too much data for what web browsers were designed for.  Compound that by adding to just a `<table>` (which needs to know everything about its content before it can render it / changes as more data is loaded) (even removing the datatable overhead) and you're heading for disaster.   Rethink how you can "showcase" your data.

Comment: @Durga Hi man, the problem you are experiencing is a combination of server and client side. You need to include more info on what you are doing on the server side to actually get valuable aid from the community.

I recommend paging. You can search for paging on almost any framework and stackoverflow should have an answer for you.

Comment: @Terrance00 Hi, Please check my updated code

Answer (score 0):

Use pagination on both server side and datatable.
When you click on next or some page number request will go to server and return the data that corresponds to that page only.

Browser cannot handle much data at a time. It is better to load data in chunks and display it on browser.

https://gist.github.com/emrekgn/d67d991f3d1a12f2bd00a12a27140485

You can refer to link for java code.

Comment: how to write code.. please provide any example code. i am using spring boot jpa repository

Comment: Any change require in front-end..i'm using HTML5 and jquery only